# Select Onchange function in two dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

What I'm trying to do is create a chained select boxes and display the information when selects. How I can connect my first dropdown to my second dropdown? When I try to add this `<select name="customers" id="customers" onchange="showUser(this.value)">` it also not working.

This like the function is http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_database.asp

What I need to do is like this http://www.melco-crown.com/eng/careerpop_js.php

What I have right now is this

```
<script>
function showUser(str,ids) {
    var $txtHint = $('#txtHint');
    if (str=="" || ids=="") {
        $txtHint.html('');
        return;
    }
    $txtHint.load('list.php?q='+str+'&id='+ids) 
}
</script>
```

I don't have problem in list.php, what I can't do is the ajax function. Any help will appreciate.

Here's my full script

**Script Loads the Information from database display in HTML table.**

```
<script>
function showUser(str) {
    var $txtHint = $('#txtHint');
    if (str=="") {
        $txtHint.html('');
        return;
    }
    $txtHint.load('list.php?q='+str)    
}
</script>
```

**HTML FORM and SELECT BOXES**

```
<form action=""> 
<select name="customers" id="customers" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a customer:</option>
<option value="ALFKI">Alfreds Futterkiste</option>
<option value="NORTS ">North/South</option>
<option value="WOLZA">Wolski Zajazd</option>
</select>
</form>
<br>

<select name="city" class="city">
<option selected="selected">--Select City--</option>
</select>
<div id="txtHint">Customer info will be listed here...</div>
```

**Ajax Script for Chained Select box**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#customers").change(function()
{
var id=$(this).val();
var dataString = 'id='+ id;

$.ajax
({
type: "POST",
url: "ajax_city.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(html)
{
$(".city").html(html);
} 
});

});
});
</script>
```

Comment: If i understand right you want to update dropdown city with info according dropdown customers? Can you provide whole code please? Where is your ajax call?

Comment: What does `list.php` return? XML, JSON, HTML?

Comment: @christian314159 It's return HTML, I edited my question.

Comment: @Alek I updated my question, I already include my ajax function. Pardon me.

Comment: I think you need an ID on the dropdown for `$('#customers')` to catch it. Example: `<select name="customers" id="customers">`

Comment: @rxgx My code right now is working. This like what my code is http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_database.asp. The problem is when I select in dropdown 2 the information shows should be between the value of dropdown 1 and 2. That's what I need to do

Comment: What "ajax_city.php" looks like?